# Why can't I load JS script in a plugin?

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I have this at the bottom of my plugin file, but while I can access the plugin, I can't see any reference in the code to **jquery.chained.min.js** in the source:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_enqueue' );

    function my_plugin_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.chained.min', plugins_url('/js/jquery.chained.min.js',__FILE__), array('jquery'));
    }
```

I have confirmed in the plugin folder that jquery.chained.min.js is in the js folder.

Comment: Are you trying to enqueue on the front or the back end?

Comment: Have you made sure that `plugins_url( 'path/to/js', __FILE__ )` points to the correct location? And where exactly do you call `add_action()`?

Comment: If you want script in frontend: do you have `wp_head()` in the template files? If in backend: you are doing it wrong. You should use `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook.